# Is there a way to navigate to other views using a UIActionSheet?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there is a way to use an Action sheet to navigate to another view?

I have a button - "Go" and an Action sheet that asks "Do you want to proceed?" and in it "Yes" and "Cancel"

Can I can navigate to another view when pressing yes?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. To do this, the `viewController` that represents the `UIActionSheet` needs to adopt `UIActionSheetDelegate`. Upon dismissing the action sheet with either Yes or Cancel, `- actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` method gets called, and from there you can navigate to another view or just ignore it.

References: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActionSheet

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIModalViewDelegate_Protocol/UIActionSheetDelegate/UIActionSheetDelegate.html

---

**Edit:**

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
-(IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender;
@end


@implementation MyViewController

-(IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do you want to procced?"  delegate:self  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"  destructiveButtonTitle:@"YES"  otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void) actionSheet: (UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex { 
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0: { 
            // for illustration
            // let's assume (1) you have a navigation controller
            // (2) you are using storyboard
            // (3) in the storyboard, you have a viewController with identifier MyChildViewControllerIdentifier
            MyChildViewController *mcvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyChildViewControllerIdentifier"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:mcvc animated:YES];
            break;
        }
         default:
            break;
     }
 }
```

P.S. I didn't run it, if there is any error, let me know to fix it.

Comment: I didn't actually understand what you said…
do u mean something like this:?


-(IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Do you want to procced?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"YES" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}

-(void) actionSheet: (UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

Comment: @OphirRam8 Yes. I added an exmaple. What part is still unclear?

Comment: i get an error: "unknown type name 'MyChildViewController', did you mean 'UiTableViewController'?"

Comment: MyChildViewController is only an example. What is your code? I have no idea what's your code, and what you are doing.

Comment: how can i write it like you did and not like my previous one

Comment: Are you referring to `MyChildViewController *mcvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyChildViewControllerIdentifier"]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:mcvc animated:YES];` ? The rest is not much different.

Comment: i mean how to show the code like you did and not all messed up together

Answer (score 1):

Dismiss the actionsheet and then `[self presentmodalviewcontroller:myview animated:yes]`